# Combining Laravel with Pug (Jade)?

Tags: laravel, pug, laravel-blade

Is it possible to easily combine Laravel Blade layouts with Pug (formerly known as Jade)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. You can use **[laravel-elixir-jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-jade)** npm package. The only problem I occurred was including mixins from external file. Everything else works perfectly.

Comment: Use [laravel-elixir-pug package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-pug) because jade one is outdated and not all of the functions are working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You may try with [laravel-pug](https://github.com/BKWLD/laravel-pug).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with pug (jade) in the same way like with blade and want to use blade in the same time then use should use https://github.com/BKWLD/laravel-pug

Comment: Have you not just copied the link from the previous answer?